# Kafka: Message Offset

Tags: apache-kafka

If records are individually posted/sent to the Kafka topic by the Producer, will each record/message have a separate offset# assigned?  OR will multiple records be combined into single message for which an offset# will be assigned?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kafka: Offset sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52732653/kafka-offset-sequence)

Comment: Please don't repost. It's not clear if you're trying to ask something different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each record will get its own offset assigned. You can refer to official doc.