# Kafka: Offset sequence

Tags: apache-kafka

Will each message posted (assuming messages are compressed) have a unique offset# assigned and remain sequential and incremental within a given partition?  Also, is it possible that the offset# sequence can reset itself, meaning it can start from 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Official documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#intro_topics) is quite clear on that:

> For each topic, the Kafka cluster maintains a partitioned log that
>   looks like this:

[image]

> Each partition is an ordered, immutable sequence of records that is
>   continually appended to—a structured commit log. The records in the
>   partitions are each assigned a sequential id number called the offset
>   that uniquely identifies each record within the partition.

Consumers are able to read from specific offsets even from the beginning:

[image]

In order to reset offsets for a particular consumer group you can use the following:

```
kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --group my-group --reset-offsets --to-earliest --all-topics --execute
```